Why the model.generate is so slow?
enter image description hereI am using one A100 to infer.The model was trained by using the alignment handbook frame and fine tuning by qlora. Then I load the model to infer and Faced with low utilization of graphics card performance and slow inference speed.
I load the model and tokenizer by the following code
device = torch.device('cuda:1')
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(path_model).to(device)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_model)

My inference code
with torch.no_grad():
        for d in tqdm(data):
            print(input_path)
            tokenized_chat = tokenizer.apply_chat_template([d[0]],return_tensors='pt',add_generation_prompt=True).to(device)
            attention_mask = torch.ones(tokenized_chat.shape,dtype=torch.long).to(device)
            input_length = tokenized_chat.shape[1]
            outputs = model.generate(tokenized_chat,attention_mask=attention_mask,max_new_tokens = 500,)
            outputs = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0][input_length:])

Please help me, Thanks~
There is a interesting phenomena that at the beginning of the inference, the speed was fast.enter image description here
